# Explaining a change in percentage from one year to the next

Tags: percentage

I recently read this sentence:

'Only 2.31% of all flats were vacant, a reduction of 27%'. Elsewhere in the publication (a page or so later) there was a graph showing that the previous year’s percentage was 3.18%.

I agree doing the calculation to determine the decrease from 3.18% to 2.31% gives one 27%. I was however, wondering if this is the correct way to explain this change in percentage. I feel this can give the reader the false impression that the change from one year to the next was much bigger than it actually is i.e. just 0.87.

I am sure statisticians often grapple with the task of putting statistics into 'words' I would therefore love to hear your opinion.

With thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I suspect that the question might be closed as primarily opinion-based. But I think the following example makes a point.] Charles Wheelan gives a similar example in his book, *Naked Statistics*, about this difference between *percentage change* and *change in percentage points*:

> The best example of this was a recent change in the Illinois personal income tax, which was raised from 3 percent to 5 percent. There are two ways to express this tax change, both of which are technically accurate. The Democrats, who engineered this tax increase, pointed out (correctly) that the state income tax rate was increased by 2 percentage points (from 3 percent to 5 percent). The Republicans pointed out (also correctly) that the state income tax had been raised by 67 percent.

So, both are technically correct, but how change is described tells us more about the author's orientation towards the issue at hand. It might be confusing, but not misleading. For instance, in this case (and I think also in yours), Wheelan argues that the latter conveys the impact of change better,

> since what I’m going to have to pay to the government—the amount that I care about, as opposed to the way it is calculated—really has gone up by 67 percent.

---

Wheelan, Charles. 2013. *Naked Statistics: Stripping the Dread from the Data*. New York and London: W.W. Norton & Company.